# PHP: Failed to write session data

Tags: php, session, nginx

I set session.save_path as 'PATH/TO/SESSION' and set chmod to this path as 777

The `file_put_contents('PATH/TO/SESSION/test.txt','hello world')` works ok, so this path should be writeable for php... But it isn't for sessions.

The `session_save_path()` shows good path: 'PATH/TO/SESSION',
but after `session_save_path('NEW/PATH/TO/SESSION')`, the `session_save_path()` still shows 'PATH/TO/SESSION'.

```
// file.php
$sessionStatus = session_start(); // returns true, without any exceptions
var_dump($_SESSION['foo']);
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
var_dump($_SESSION['foo']);
// end of file.php
```

When I open this file.php, it still generates warning on end of file:

```
Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (PATH/TO/SESSION) in Unknown on line 0
```

And after page reload, the `$_SESSION['foo']` is not set.

New session file is created, but its size is 0 bytes.

PHP 5.5, server nginx 1.8, Linux.

Comment: Can you show the path ?

Comment: /home/www.example.com/session, as the same dir-level as /home/www.example.com/public_html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `session_save_path()` before you call `session_start()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the session save path before starting the session.

```
Session data path. If specified, the path to which data is saved will be changed. session_save_path() needs to be called before session_start() for that purpose.
```

From the php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this for the custom path.

session_save_path('/home/example.com/sessions');

ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);

Comment: Have you tried ini_set('session.save_path',getcwd(). '/tmp');   this stores in subfolder name as tmp